# I couldn't create react app , its throwing some error

Tags: create-react-app

I entered this below command to create react app in my system,
npx create-react-app appname --template redux

And am getting the following error,
You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

I tried below solution too ,
To install node,

npm install npm@latest -g

Before using create-react-app make sure you clean npm cache using
npm cache clean --force

For this command (npm cache clean --force) , getting below error

npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled

Any solution for this plz?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved using the following command.

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

And

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```